# Too many templates in Django

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and I programming a CRUD for various objects. Currently I need to generate three templates per object: one for creation, one for update and one for a list. Look at how many templates I got in the picture.

The process is becoming painful.

What I am doing wrong and how to correct it?

Thanks.

[image: templates]

Comment: This is better than putting all html into a ***single*** template

Comment: It might be possible to have create, list and update templates that work for all models, but it depends on your models, views, and how much the templates vary.

Comment: The problem is that If I need to make a change, for example, add a new button, I have to make it in all the templates. Anyway, am I doing good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment:

> The problem is that If I need to make a change, for example, add a new button, I have to make it in all the templates.

That sounds wrong. Either a button belong to one type of thing and then it should only exist in that template, or it should be on every page and then it should be in the *base template*.

You can make one template with your basic page layout (including such buttons), and have "blocks" in them that are then filled out by each template that *extends* the base template.

See [the Django documentation about template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance).

Also, I think that in most cases the "create" and "update" pages are going to be extremely similar; usually they use the same template, one with data already filled in, the other without.

You could have a base template, then a generic list template and a generic edit/create template, with templates for each type of thing extending the list and the edit templates to fill in only the relevant fields.

Also, maybe you use HTML that is close enough to what the Django forms can render themselves. Then as long as you call the edit/create form the same in each of your views (like "form"), the template can just render the form and they can all use the same template.

Comment: That's Good, That's Really Good Recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you're building a big web-app then this is normal for templates to be more.

Heavy (big) web-app means = more templates + more code + more time + more features
```